# conversion from asp.net web site(.aspx pages) to WCF service

Tags: asp.net

i have developed a web site using asp.net. In the web site if user enters username and password he will proceed to the next pages say home.aspx, dailyreport.aspx which is correct.
But the problem i'm facing is if the user enters url of the any page say domainname/projectname/dailyreport, then he will be in the desired page. then what is the use of having login page... how to deal with this issue....can anybody please help me. please as soosn as possible....

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum, you need to enable Forms Authentication. This will ensure that any unauthorised users are redirected to a login page, from where they can access the site.

For more information about Forms Authentication, try this;

[Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)